# MongoDB Bulk Insert Performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

I have the following code in my rails app.

```
module UserItem
  class Rating
    include MongoMapper::Document
    key :user_id, Integer, :required => true
    key :item_id,  Integer, :required => true
    key :rating, Float, :required => true 
  end
end
```

And I have about 10K users and 10K items and i need to store rating of each user for each item, which is about 10^8 records. I have computed the values of 10^8 records into an array as follows

```
ratings = [
  {user_id: 1, item_id: 1, rating: 1.5}, 
  {user_id: 1, item_id: 2, rating: 3.5},
  ... and so on 10^8 records
]
```

Now, I need to insert all these 10^8 records computed into mongo. I tried with

```
UserItem::Rating.collection.insert(ratings)
```

and

```
UserItem::Rating.create(ratings)
```

But it takes hours together to insert the 10^8 records into mongo. Is there any better/efficient way to insert records into mongo?

**Context:** I am using it more like a cache store which stores all rating values. When I display list of items, I will just read from this cache and display the rating provided by the user alongside each item.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I've got a similar setup in that I'm storing predict rating for all users for products - I ended up storing one document per user that has a hash of item_ids to rating values. Probably not so good if you only need 1 or 2 ratings at a time

Comment: @FrederickCheung Thats a great idea! But in my case, i need both the things, 1. Given a user - i need all items he rated along with rating and 2. Given a item - i need all users who rated it along with rating.

Comment: You can insert multiple documents at once in many drivers. You might want to disable the write concern (so it doesn't wait for a response). Turn off indexes during insertion ...

Comment: Thanks @WiredPrairie! I will try the following 1. disable write concern 2. disable indexes. Is sharding the way to go here or sharing is not the approach?

Comment: If you have multiple servers, sharding should help by distributing the writes.

Comment: We have only single instance now. But If there is no other way to write faster to a single instance, apart from sharding, we will have to work on having multiple instances.

Comment: @FrederickCheung I am actually trying out the way you suggested. How did you implement **hash of item_ids to rating values**. Did you do that with EmbeddedDocument? Can you provide some details on the data structure you tried, as an answer for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to store one document per user, with a ratings field that is a hash of item ids to users, for example

```
class UserRating
  include MongoMapper::Document
  key :ratings
  key :user_id
end

UserRating.create(:user_id => 1, :ratings => {"1" => 4, "2" => 3})
```

You have to use string keys for the hash. This approach doesn't make it easy to retrieve all the ratings for a given document - if you do that a lot it might be easier to store a document per item instead. It's also probably not very efficient if you only ever need a small proportion of a user's ratings at a time.

Obviously you can combine this with other approaches to increasing write throughput, such as batching your inserts or sharding your database.